# Why does Spring-boot no longer load PKCS11-NSS certificates after update to 3.1.0?

Tags: springboot

After updating from spring-boot version 3.0.8 to 3.1.0 or 3.1.1 the application no longer loads the SSL certificates from the store.

Configuration:
FIPS compliant config as described in:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/openjdk/17/html/configuring_openjdk_17_on_rhel_with_fips/openjdk-default-fips-configuration#key_store

Application is standalone tomcat embedded service.

Configuration file contents:

/path/to/application.properties

...........Clipped for Brevity

security.require-ssl=true

server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS11

server.ssl.key-store-password=passwd

server.ssl.key-alias=Server-Cert

server.ssl.protocol=TLS

server.ssl.enabled-protocols=TLSv1.2

...........Clipped for Brevity

/etc/alternatives/jre_17/conf/security/java.security

...........Clipped for Brevity

security.provider.12=SunPKCS11 /etc/alternatives/jre_17/conf/security/nss.cfg

...........Clipped for Brevity

/etc/alternatives/jre_17/conf/security/nss.cfg

name = NSSfips

nssLibraryDirectory = /usr/lib64

nssSecmodDirectory = /etc/pki/certs/nss

nssModule = fips

nssDbMode = readOnly

nssUseSecmod = true

This configuration has been working for almost 4 years without issue.
I understand there was an update that support for SSL bundles, however it also stated that current server.ssl support would continue to function.

Is there something I need to change in the configuration now to get it to load the certificates?

Steps taken to correct: I've tried to isolate loading of the certificates by enabling debug mode and using process trace utilities. However it seems to skip the configuration all together and starts the application without a certificate. No errors in the logs.

I was going to post an issue in the Github/spring-boot repository and it said to try here first.